# How to split numbers in DataFrame with comma or dot in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some transform about numbers like 100000 to 100.000 in Python. How can I do that ?

I tried it with using Format(number,'.d'). But I have DataFrame, or List. When I execute the code, it says unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.**format**

```
users = data.iloc[:,[3]].values.astype(str)


for i in range(len(users)):
    users[i] = (format (users[i], ',d'))
```

```
users[i] = (format (users[i], ',d'))
```

> TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.**format**

Comment: Give full code to help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative way to achieve what you're trying to do without using the format function but relying on locale module instead:

```
import pandas
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf-8')

users = pandas.DataFrame(data=[100, 1000, 10000, 100000], columns=["colA"])
users["colA"] = [locale.format("%d", v, 1) for v in users.iloc[:,0]]
print(users)
```

Outcome:

```
      colA
0      100
1    1.000
2   10.000
3  100.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You're applying format on a series basically, not specifying the axis either.

Try this, it'll add comma(s) to all the values in 3rd column:

```
df.iloc[:,[3]] = df.iloc[:,[3]].apply(lambda x:format (x.values[0], ',d'), axis=1)
```